# iphone-AVAudioPlayer Overlaps

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I have a button that plays an AVAudiplayer sound file every time I click it. The file is a relatively short .mp3 lazer sound. So, I declared an AVAUdiplayer, and prepeared it to play in the viewDidLoad funcition in my code. That worked fine. Then, I wrote [audioPlayer play] when the button gets clicked. This also worked fine. The problem is when I click the button repeatedly, the sound from the first button click does not cut off until it is done, even if there is overlap. So, the next sound doesn't play until the other one is finished. Answer with code please.

Answer (score 0):

Check if its playing first. If it is stop it then play.

```
  if (audioPlayer.rate != 0.0f) [audioPlayer stop];

    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: There's no downside to stopping it when it isn't playing.  So no need to check first.

Comment: @Rookie Also, would that have any lag if I am clicking the button to play the sound really fast?

Comment: what doesn't work? can you be more clear, please provide some code

Comment: @Rookie Here is my code in the view did load function:  `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"/lazer"
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:url
               error:&error];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];`

Comment: @Rookie Then, I call it in a function called fire using your code suggested. This still has my overlap problem.